# VB.net Problem with Packet Length Prefixing TCP

Tags: vb.net

I am having a problem with reading prefixes of the length of the TCP packets I am sending.
Every packet is prefixed with a 32 bit integer that is the length of the packet.
The problem is that sometimes (not on localhost, only over the internet) I am having a problem that the BitConverter.ToInt32 is returning a negative number or an abnormally high one (Out of Memory exception). So this causes my server to crash. This happens when I am sending the remote desktop of a client to my server. I am using the SocketAsyncEventArgs class, and everything works on localhost...

The class i use:
[Server Part](https://github.com/aeonhack/archive/blob/master/sources/pastebin/buffered_server_(socket).vb)
[Client Part](https://github.com/aeonhack/archive/blob/master/sources/pastebin/buffered_client_(socket).vb)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to [edit] your question to improve them, for example to include a [mcve] inside the question itself.

Comment: Should you be perhaps using `UInteger` rather than `Integer`? It supports twice the range of positive numbers because it doesn't support negative numbers. The same 32 bits that represent a `UInteger` greater than `Integer.MaxValue` would represent a negative `Integer` value`. Mind you, a packet that size seems a bit far-fetched.

Comment: [Interlocked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.interlocked) Class

Comment: What size are the TCP segments that are being sent? Can you arrange to use quite small segments (maybe 700 bytes or so just for testing) so that the MTU size for the internet connection is not exceeded? This *could* be irrelevant.